# Mongoid 1-N relationship (one to many) in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am trying to build 1-N (one-many) relationship between two entities in Rails 4 with Mongoid. So far I have created a simple app with 'Blog' & 'Comment' (each blog contains multiple comments).

I am using `has_many` attribute to define the relationship. Here what I have got so far...

```
class Blog
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    has_many  :comments, validate: false

    field :title, type: String
    field :content, type: String
end


class Comment
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    belongs_to :blog

    field :title, type: String
    field :content, type: String
end
```

This is what my Blog#Show view file looks
https://github.com/som-poddar/Mongo_One_Many/blob/master/app/views/blogs/show.html.erb

after several try, I always end up with...

```
Showing /Users/spoddar/work/Mongo_One_Many/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f1d08e5f8>:0x007f9f1f9b6458>
```

Can someone help me out?
Full Source Code at https://github.com/som-poddar/Mongo_One_Many

My Routes...

```
Prefix Verb              URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
    blog_comments GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /blogs/:blog_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)                            blogs#index
                  POST   /blogs(.:format)                            blogs#create
         new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)                        blogs#new
        edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)                   blogs#edit
             blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#show
                  PATCH  /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#update
                  PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#update
                  DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your `comments/_form.html.erb` page, specifically this line: `form_for (@comment) do |f|`.

If you look at your routes file, the `comments#create` action is mapped to the following route: `/blogs/:blog_id/comments(.:format)`. However `form_for(@comment)` will generate a link to the following route: `/comments`. This is what is raising the error.

To fix this, you need to let rails know that your comments resource is nested under the blogs resource. In other words, you must pass `form_for` an array of your blog object as well as your comment object, and rails magic will generate the correct route.

So change your code to the following:

```
<%= form_for([@blog, @comment]) do |f| %>
  # stuff here
<% end %>
```

In order for this solution to work, the `comments/_form.html.erb` form must have access to the `@blog` instance variable. This means that if you call `render 'form'` in your `comments/new.html.erb` page, the `CommentsController#new` must set a `@blog` instance variable in addition to the `@comment` instance variable. So your `CommentsController#new` action must look something like this:

```
def new
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
  @comment = @blog.comments.build
end
```

Likewise, your create action should also be loading the blog model, something along the lines of:

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
  @comment = @blog.comments.build
  @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
  respond_with(@comment)
end
```

For more information about nested resources, refer to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

---

Your current errors are unrelated to your original nested routing / 1-N relationship problem.

- Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound in CommentsController#edit. This error is caused by improperly using the `Blog.find` method. When you pass `Blog.find` multiple ids, it will return an array of blogs with the given ids. You called find with `params[:id]` and `params[:blog_id]`. Given that you are in `CommentsController`, `params[:id]` presumably contains the id of a `comment` object, in other words a `blog` object with the given id does not exist. According to Mongoid's documentation [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html), the find method will raise an error by default if any of the ids do not match, hence the `Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound` error.

If you are trying to load a comment in your `set_comment` method, then the correct code would be

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

- undefined method model_name for Mongoid::Criteria:Class. Looking at your repo, this is similarly caused by improperly using Mongoid's queryable DSL.

`CommentsController#set_comment` is again at fault.

```
def set_comment
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
  @comment = @blog.comments.where(:_id => params[:id])
end
```

This time, you are correctly loading the blog. However, `@blog.comments.where(:_id => params[:id])` will return a collection of comments with the id matching the given param. In your particular case, it will return a collection of a single element, however the class of @comment is `Mongoid::Criteria` rather than `Comment`, as you probably intended. One solution might be to change that line to:

```
@comment = @blog.comments.where(:_id => params[:id]).first
```

This line of code will return the first element of the collection of comments, or `nil` if no such comment exists.

Another solution would be to load that comment via the `find` method as well:

```
@comment = @blog.comments.find(params[:id])
```

or equivalently:

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

You should probably read through the Mongoid querying document linked above if any of that was unclear, as well as the rails activerecord querying guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: I tried your suggestions, still no result. Do I need to adjust Comment#Create method. Please see... https://github.com/som-poddar/Mongo_One_Many/blob/master/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb#L33

Comment: all my latest changes are checked in. Unzip this folder for screenshots. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/271517271/errors.zip

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your routes?

I think your route in this case is: blogs_comments_path, not just comments_path.

check this running $ bundle exec rake -T

Just to explain better, you your route file:
https://github.com/som-poddar/Mongo_One_Many/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L2

you are using nested relationships, that's why your route is slightly different.
an example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: I fixed the route. Now I have new problems. Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your `config/routes.rb`

since you define your **Comment Controller** as *nested resource* under **Blog Controller**, the path should be called `blog_comments_path`

Comment: if you take a look at the latest changes in the Github repo, the prefix for the routes are correct. But, I am not able to 'embed' 'Comment:Name' & 'Comment:Title' inside the 'Blog' document. Also, the code to create a 'new' comment is throwing exception

Comment: when I try to 'Edit' a comment for a blog, I see 'Problem: Document(s) not found for class Blog with id(s)'.